# how can make the Lists that i have appended within the lists appear on different lines when printed altogethor in python?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I want to create a report card like program as a part of a school coding project, it has to be simple and use some basic functions and loops in python.

```
`sn = int(input("Enter Number of Students: "))
 reportCard = []
 header = ["Name","Total","Average","Result","Grade"]
 for i in range(sn):
    reportCard.append([])
    name = str(input("Name of Student: "))
    m1 = float(input("enter achieved marks in First Subject: "))
    m2 = float(input("enter achieved marks in Second Subject: "))
    m3 = float(input("enter achieved marks in Third Subject: "))
    total = m1 + m2 + m3
    average = total/3
    ResultS = " "
    grade = " "
    if average >= 60:
        ResultS = "Passed"
    else:
        ResultS= "Failed"
    if average < 60:
        grade = "F"
    elif average <= 70:
        grade = "D"
    elif average <= 75:
        grade = "C"
    elif average <= 80:
        grade = "B"
    elif average <= 85:
        grade = "A-"
    elif average <= 90:
        grade = "A"
    elif average <= 95:
        grade = "A+"
    elif average <= 100:
        grade = "A*"
    x = [name, total, average, ResultS, grade]
    reportCard[i].append(x)

    if i == sn-1:
      print()
      print ("Report Card")
      print()
      print("Name","Total","Average","Result","Grade")
      print(*reportCard)
      break`
```

The output needs to look like this:

```
Name total average results Grade
name total average results grade
```

but looks like this instead=

```
Name total average results Grade, name total average results grade
```

any ideas how to get it fixed??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use \n to change to a new line.

```
print("Name","Total","Average","Result","Grade\n")
print(*reportCard)
```

Some other escape characters:

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html